# Form issues sending an id to a new page for $_GET

Tags: php

Having trouble getting the `$row['post_topic']` to actually pass the id over to reply page. If I input an ID manually, for example '2', it works absolutely fine.

```
echo '<form method="post" action="reply.php?id=' .$row['post_topic']. '">
          <textarea name="reply-content"></textarea>
          <input type="submit" value="Replyy" />
      </form>';
```

**Edit**

An extra note, `echo $row['post_topic'];` works inside one of the While loops I have in the same file.

Query:

```
$sql= "SELECT 
           posts.post_topic,
           posts.post_content,
           posts.post_date,
           posts.post_by,
           users.user_id,
           users.user_name
       FROM
           posts
       LEFT JOIN
           users
       ON
           posts.post_by = users.user_id
       WHERE
           posts.post_topic = 
              '" .mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['id']). "'";
```

PHP:

```
$row = $resultpost->fetch_assoc();

echo $row['post_topic'];

echo '<br><table border="0"';
  echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>';
      echo '<form method="post" action="reply.php?id='.$row['post_topic']. '">
                 <textarea name="reply-content"></textarea>
                 <input type="submit" value="Reply" />
            </form>';
    echo '</th>';
  echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: That is not enough information. Where does $row come from, what is the query, and what is in the DB.

Comment: What does `echo $row['post_topic'];` give you?

Comment: Added more information on the post to aid.

Comment: Looks like it could be a data type issue.  Using gettype($row['post_topic']) what is the output?  String? Int?

Comment: The issue arose after I checked, `gettype()` returned NULL. I had to execute the query again, despite having done so already. It's a fix for now that's good enough.

Comment: Sounds good, glad to hear it

Answer (score 0):

Check the data type using `gettype($row['post_topic'])`. This may be the issue.